# How limit the rows to 3 and sum the amounts for each day of the week?

Tags: oracle

I need to aggregate a result to 3 rows for April, May and June respectively while I get a sum for each day of the week (Monday to Sunday) for those 3 rows.I tried using distinct to remove the redundant month names but it didn't work.

```
select distinct t.calendar_month_name as "SALES_MONTH", 
case when t.day_number_in_week = 1 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as MONDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 2 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as TUESDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 3 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as WEDNESDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 4 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as THURSDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 5 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as FRIDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 6 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as SATURDAY,
case when t.day_number_in_week = 7 then sum(s.amount_sold) else 0 end as SUNDAY
from products p
join sales s on p.prod_id = s.prod_id
join times t on t.time_id = s.TIME_ID
where
p.prod_id = 5  and 
t.calendar_year = 2000 and
t.calendar_quarter_number = 2
group by t.calendar_month_name, t.day_number_in_week
having sum(s.amount_sold) > 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: Sample data and your expected output would be helpful.

Comment: 1st column called MONTHS under which April, May and June are expected to be shown. Then 7 more columns, each is called Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday under which the data is a summed amount of products sold. How to aggregate that to return only the summed amounts and not 0? I wish I could show a screenshot, would make things far easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the PROD table here. In my SH schema, I don't have PROD_ID = 5 so I used 13.

```
select * from (
  select t.calendar_month_name, t.day_number_in_week,
    sum(s.amount_sold) amount_sold
  from sales s
  join times t on t.time_id = s.TIME_ID
  where
  s.prod_id = 13  and 
  t.calendar_year = 2000 and
  t.calendar_quarter_number = 2
  group by t.calendar_month_name, t.day_number_in_week
  having sum(s.amount_sold) > 1
)
pivot(sum(amount_sold) for day_number_in_week in (
  1 as MONDAY,
  2 as TUESDAY,
  3 as WEDNESDAY,
  4 as THURSDAY,
  5 as FRIDAY,
  6 as SATURDAY,
  7 as SUNDAY
))
order by 1;

CALENDAR_     MONDAY    TUESDAY  WEDNESDAY   THURSDAY     FRIDAY   SATURDAY     SUNDAY
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
April       20792,32   35724,12   43189,77   16688,08    11436,9              49960,37
June        27037,04   16809,54   11504,03              37709,26   23923,83   35908,33
May                   123982,43   18773,74               5283,56              21167,23
```

If there was no HAVING filter, you would not need the GROUP BY in the inline view because the implicit grouping of the PIVOT clause would be enough:

```
select * from (
  select t.calendar_month_name, t.day_number_in_week,
    s.amount_sold
  from sales s
  join times t on t.time_id = s.TIME_ID
  where
  s.prod_id = 13  and 
  t.calendar_year = 2000 and
  t.calendar_quarter_number = 2
)
pivot(sum(amount_sold) for day_number_in_week in (
  1 as MONDAY,
  2 as TUESDAY,
  3 as WEDNESDAY,
  4 as THURSDAY,
  5 as FRIDAY,
  6 as SATURDAY,
  7 as SUNDAY
))
order by 1;
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton